# How to add thumbnails in Google searched results?

Tags: joomla, seo

I am using joomla 3.3 and my website is http://www.goodfoodseeker.com/ 
Whenever I search any article of my website in Google, why it's searched results doesn't show thumbnail of that article?
I have attached print screen of my searched article. The second link is my article and its only showing title name, description, date and url link but not showing thumbnail of that particular article.
Please Help
Regards
Neha

Comment: What do you mean by "not showing thumbnail"? Are you sure your website is crawled by google?

Comment: Yes, it is being crawled by Google long back... I am aware of micro data recipe markup but doesn't know how to apply it.

Comment: do you have any example how do you want to display it? Have you consider to apply the http://schema.org/

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you've got the basic Opengraph data, but if you want to use the recipe schema you'll need to either:

1. Use a third party extension which allows you to set this on a per-article basis (there are several in the JED)
2. Create a template override, and hard-code the schema markup into your template so that it automatically picks up the relevant information - only possible if you have the data for the recipe-specific fields in a field you can wrap in itemprop tags

You might also find this article helpful in explaining how to use Microdata: http://magazine.joomla.org/issues/issue-july-2014/item/2161-practical-use-of-microdata-in-joomla-3-and-2-5